Handling Mount Unit Failures on Boot in Ubuntu 22.04 Without Impacting System Performance
This issue arises during the boot process of Ubuntu 22.04. Despite the system operating normally without any significant performance drawbacks, I consistently encounter a series of error messages related to mount unit failures. The system check reports the following:
/dev/nvme0n1p7: clean, 2041902/42721280 files, 67243365/170864384 blocks
[    2.464992] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/canonical-livepatch_229.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    2.464992] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/canonical-livepatch_229.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    2.468568] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/chromium_2614.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    2.471267] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_15925.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    2.472090] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_16202.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    2.482007] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_3068.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    2.484331] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/firefox_3206.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    2.487835] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_120.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    2.490344] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-42-2204_141.snap: Can't open blockdev
[    2.498566] /var/lib/snapd/snaps/slack_89.snap: Can't open blockdev
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for canonical-livepatch, revision 229.
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for chromium, revision 2614.
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for core, revision 15925.
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for core, revision 16202.
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for firefox, revision 3068.
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for firefox, revision 3206.
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for gnome-42-2204, revision 120.
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for gnome-42-2204, revision 141.
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for slack, revision 89.

These messages indicate an inability to open blockdev for various snaps during boot, followed by failures to mount their respective units.
While these errors do not seem to hamper the functionality of the OS, I am concerned about potential underlying issues that may not be immediately evident. Additionally, I am interested in understanding the cause of these errors and how to resolve them for a cleaner boot process.
Here are the troubleshooting steps I've already attempted:
Checked the filesystem for errors using fsck.
Ensured that all snap packages are updated to their latest versions.
Attempted to manually remount the mentioned units with no success.
I would be grateful for any insights into the following questions:
What could be the potential cause of these error messages during the boot process?
Is there a way to fix these mount unit failures without impacting the current system stability?
Are these errors indicative of an impending system issue that requires preemptive action?
Any advice or diagnostic recommendations would be highly appreciated!
PS This's what I've got after snap list --all:
snap list --all
Name                        Version           Rev    Tracking         Publisher       Notes
bare                        1.0               5      latest/stable    canonical✓      base
canonical-livepatch         10.8.2            278    latest/stable    canonical✓      -
canonical-livepatch         10.8.1            264    latest/stable    canonical✓      disabled
chromium                    124.0.6367.60     2828   latest/stable    canonical✓      disabled
chromium                    124.0.6367.91     2839   latest/stable    canonical✓      -
core                        16-2.61.2         16928  latest/stable    canonical✓      core
core                        -                 16202  latest/stable    canonical✓      disabled, broken
core18                      20240416          2823   latest/stable    canonical✓      base
core18                      20231027          2812   latest/stable    canonical✓      base, disabled
core20                      20230801          2015   latest/stable    canonical✓      base, disabled
core20                      20240227          2264   latest/stable    canonical✓      base
core22                      20240408          1380   latest/stable    canonical✓      base
core22                      20240111          1122   latest/stable    canonical✓      base, disabled
cups                        2.4.8-1           1047   latest/stable    openprinting✓   -
cups                        2.4.7-8           1044   latest/stable    openprinting✓   disabled
firefox                     125.0.3-1         4209   latest/stable/...mozilla✓        -
firefox                     125.0.2-1         4173   latest/stable/...mozilla✓        disabled
gnome-3-34-1804             0+git.3556cb3     93     latest/stable    canonical✓      -
gnome-3-38-2004             0+git.6f39565     140    latest/stable/...canonical✓      disabled
gnome-3-38-2004             0+git.efb213a     143    latest/stable/...canonical✓      -
gnome-42-2204               0+git.510a601     176    latest/stable    canonical✓      -
gnome-42-2204               -                 141    latest/stable    canonical✓      disabled, broken
gtk-common-themes           0.1-81-g442e511   1535   latest/stable/...canonical✓      -
keepassxc                   2.7.6             1762   latest/stable    keepassxreboot  -
kf5-5-105-qt-5-15-9-core22  5.105             11     latest/stable    kde✓            -
slack                       4.36.138          130    latest/stable    slack✓          disabled
slack                       4.37.101          142    latest/stable    slack✓          -
snap-store                  41.3-71-g709398e  959    latest/stable/...canonical✓      disabled
snap-store                  41.3-77-g7dc86c8  1113   latest/stable/...canonical✓      -
snapd                       2.61.1            20671  latest/stable    canonical✓      snapd, disabled
snapd                       2.62              21465  latest/stable    canonical✓      snapd
snapd-desktop-integration   0.9               157    latest/stable/...canonical✓      -
snapd-desktop-integration   0.9               83     latest/stable/...canonical✓      disabled
enter code here


The revisions of the mentioned snaps seems to be pretty old, are they still installed? Check with snap list --all. I guess this snaps have been already removed from your system. May be the removal was somehow incomplete and there are some leftovers which cause this behaviour.

I tried snap list --all, it seems you're right, mook765. What do you recommend to get rid of these 'old' paquettes? Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Hard to say what is the best thing to do here. I hesitate to just delete files from the system since I don't know if that would lead to further problems or not. You could disable the mount units. Example: systemctl list-units | grep slack, systemctl status snap-slack-89.mount, sudo systemctl disable snap-slack-89.mount. You may need to adapt the commands according to the output of the list-units command.

I spent a lot of time troubleshooting before determining that snap packages were the cause of the frequent mount unit failures during boot. These boot issues were eventually fixed by uninstalling snap support from Ubuntu 22.04.
Not everyone will find this option suitable, particularly if you depend on snap packages. It's important to balance the snaps' functionality with your system's boot stability. I hope this is helpful to anyone experiencing similar problems with Ubuntu's mount unit.

I had a couple of similar warnings (for firefox_4451 & core_162).
To remove the boot messages I just did a search of the issues:
sudo find /etc/systemd/system -name 'snap-xx*'

Then I moved these files - wasn't sure I could've deleted them:
sudo mv /etc/systemd/system/*/snap-code-162.mount{,.bak}

(or sudo rm -v /etc/systemd/system/*/snap-code-162.mount)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
